# FlashPlayer For .net Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

How to use flash player (axshockwaveflash) in dotnet compact framwork 3.5?
I can add axshockwaveflash to the reference but i don't have UI for that.

```
ShockwaveFlashObjects.ShockwaveFlash flash = new ShockwaveFlashObjects.ShockwaveFlash();            
            flash.LoadMovie(0, "sample.swf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add COM and ActiveX support in .NET Compact Framework using odyssey software CFCOM:

See the [Microsoft Develop Network Instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446494.aspx) to do this.